# Proving an equality

Tags: computational-complexity

Let $f(n) = n^ {\log n}$. Let $p(n)$ and $q(n) \geq n$ be polynomials. I want to show that for
$n$ sufficiently large $f (n)$ satisfies
$$p(n) < f (n) < 2^{q(n)}$$

starting from the above inequality doesn't yield any satisfying result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p(n)$ is a polynomial,
$p(n) < c n^d$ where $d$ is the degree of $p$
and $c$ is the sum of the absolute value of its coefficients.
So $p(n) < n^{d+1}$ for $n > c$.
Therefore,
if $\log n > d+1$,
$p(n) < f(n)$.

For the upper bound,
$f(n) = n^{\log n}
= e^{\log^2 n}
= 2^{(\log^2 n)/\log 2}
$,
so any polynomial $q$ such that
$q(n) > (\log^2 n)/\log 2$
will work.
Since $(\log^2 n)/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$,
any polynomial will work.

Comment: Not *any*, as with $q(x)=-x$ we have $2^{q(n)}\to 1$. Nonconstant with positive leading term is needed, as guaranteed by the OP's condition $q(n)\ge n$.